# What does the *borrow in somebody* mean?

Tags: meaning

> I'm in and Jupiter works for me (have a client with a lil waterfront shack I can borrow in Jupiter).

The comment of the article.
http://seekingalpha.com/article/4027602-ding-dong-net-worth-sweep-dead-yet
[image]
I understand the sentence omitted *in Jupiter*.

> I'm in and Jupiter works for me (have a client with a lil waterfront shack I can borrow ).

What does the  *in Jupiter* mean?
There is no idiom *borrow sth in sb*,just *borrow sth from sb*.

Comment: The link in your question appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Suggest "In" is a mistake for "on", the shack is located "on" the planet Jupiter (haven't tried link though)

Comment: [*Jupiter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter,_Florida) is a town in Florida. It is the waterfront shack that he can borrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter,_Florida)

is a town in Florida on the north side of Palm Beach County.

However, considering your source is seekingalpha.com, if it's waterfront property you're looking for then

> [Jupiter Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Island,_Florida)

is probably what the author is talking about.

> *"The population was 817 at the 2010 census. Some of the wealthiest people in the United States live in Jupiter Island: Worth magazine ranked it #1 in the country for having the highest median home sale, and it has the highest per capita income of any inhabited place in the country."*

The locals refer to it simply as "Jupiter" and to say there are "waterfront shacks" is an understatement. Nice place to hang out...